# Add two times laravel

Tags: laravel, time

I have two times `$first = 16 (seconds or minutes)` & `$second = 10 (seconds or minutes)`

**What i want to achieve** - I want to add this two times like `$result = $first + $second` & the result is in seconds & minutes formet
like

```
$first = 16 seconds;
$second = 2 minutes;
$result = $first + $second;  // 2 minutes, 16 seconds
```

so, how can we do this in code

I have this refrence code to get the time interval of two times

```
$in1 = explode(' ', "clock in time = 20 minutes");
$out1 = explode(' ', "clock out time = 10 minutes");
        
$start_time1 = $in1[4] . ' ' . $in1[5];
$end_time1 = $out1[4] . ' ' . $out1[5];
        
$start1 = Carbon::parse($start_time1);
$end1 = Carbon::parse($end_time1);

$dd1 = $end1->diffForHumans($start1, [
    'parts' => 2,
    'join' => ', ',
    'syntax' => CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE,
]);
```

Comment: How you want to determine, second or minutes in $first and $second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon intervals allow you to create an interval instance from strings like `20 minutes` or `10 seconds` so you can leverage that with some date operations to get what you need:

```
$in1 = explode('=', "clock in time = 20 minutes");
$out1 = explode('=', "clock out time = 10 minutes");
        
$startinterval = CarbonInterval::fromString(trim($in1[1]));
$endinterval = CarbonInterval::fromString(trim($out1[1]));
$now = CarbonImmutable::now();
$interval = $now->add($startinterval)->add($endinterval)->diffAsCarbonInterval($now);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your times in seconds, do the addition, then convert to time again.

```
$start = $in1[5] === 'seconds' ? $int1[4] : $int1[4] * 60;
$end = $out1[5] === 'seconds' ? $out1[4] : $out1[4] * 60; 

$totalInSeconds = (int) $start + (int) $end;

$dd1 = gmdate('i', $totalInSeconds) .' minutes, '. gmdate('s', $totalInSeconds) .' seconds';
echo $dd1;
```